# iOS Universal Links: Rails backend

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ios-universal-links

1. I have set successfully a backend server on Rails with **apple-app-site-association** file in the root i.e.

   https://example.com/apple-app-site-association
2. In iOS app the entitlements mentioned are correct i.e

   applinks:id.example.com
3. Content of the **apple-app-site-association** file on server is also correct.

But when I'm testing the universal links then it is not working.
The content for the file contains two app domains one for staging and on for production. The universal link is working fine in production app but not in staging app

Comment: Does you staging domain https or http?

Comment: @AravindAR it is https

Comment: Then in the normal case it should work. 
Since it works for production, the only chance that I feel is some mistake may be typo in the paths field specifying the staging server

Comment: I cross checked it everything is fine.

Comment: Have you tried using validator tools like
https://branch.io/resources/universal-links/ or
https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool

Comment: Does the appId for the current building target correctly added against staging path ?

Comment: @AravindAR yes the appId is added.

Comment: oh can't figure out the cause